# UITableViewCell - Giving nil value

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` Method of tableView , I am saving some data in `NSUserDefault` like this

```
UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSUserDefaults *storeData=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[storeData setObject:selectedCell.textLabel.text forKey:@"tpName"];
```

However I am not getting the selectedCell.textLabel.text value . It is giving me nil value . there is a text there on the particular row . Delegate and Datasource are set Properly .

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: How do you populate the label with text in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you shouldn't be taking the text from the cell anyway. You add the text to the cell before it is displayed as you are the data source. You should be using the index path to get the appropriate text from your data model and then store it.

Comment: Ok wain . I used that indexpath for fetching the data from the data model .. It did worked .. Thanks

Comment: Remember to vote and tick answers, it helps the system work (and makes me smile :-)  )

Comment: yes ... it is allowing me to tick only after 10 mins . you always give me answer before that !!!! :D